# how to split date & time from xml

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

i have an XML file which contain date & time like this

```
  <date>3/24/2014</date>
  <time>9:00 AM</time>
</playdate>
```

i store this data in a data set & want to add in data table. i write this code for getting data

```
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["StartDate"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                dr["StartTime"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
```

But the problem is when i export data in excel file i got both date & time in excel file in same column. i want date in my StartDate & time in  StartTime . how can i split XML data

**EDIT**

```
        string url = @"c:\temp\TestXML.xml";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(url);
        string input = reader.ReadToEnd();
        input = input.Trim();
        input = input.Replace("- <", " <");
        input = input.Replace(" & ", " &#38; ");
        input = input.Replace("W&W", "W&#38;W");
        input = input.Replace("", "&#13;");
        int userid = 0;
        int j = 1;

        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(input));
            // Creating Data Table according to Table Value Parameter in Database
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CalenderName", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EventName", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StartDate", typeof(DateTime)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EndDate", typeof(DateTime)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StartTime", typeof(DateTime)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EndTime", typeof(DateTime)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Venue", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("City", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("State", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ZipCode", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PhoneNo", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Link", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Email", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Performer", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Tags", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Price", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PriceURL", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EventDetails", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TimeZoneName", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TimeZoneOffsetAtCreation", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TabIndex", typeof(int)));

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                string sDate = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                string sTime = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                DateTime dDateTime;
                //cond: for checking the datetime parsing
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(sDate, "m/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDateTime))
                {
                    //sDate  = dDateTime.ToString("M/dd/yyyy");
                    //dr["StartDate"] = sDate;  
                    dr["StartDate"] = dDateTime;
                }
                //cond: for checking the datetime parsing
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(sTime, "hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDateTime))
                {
                    //sTime  = dDateTime.ToString("h:mm:ss");
                    //dr["StartTime"] = sTime;
                    dr["StartTime"] = dDateTime;
                }
                dr["EventName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                //dr["StartDate"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                //dr["EndDate"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                //dr["StartTime"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                //dr["EndTime"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                dr["Venue"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                dr["Address"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][2].ToString();
                dr["City"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][4].ToString();
                dr["State"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][5].ToString();
                dr["ZipCode"] = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][6].ToString());
                dr["PriceURL"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
                dr["EventDetails"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                j++;
            }

            gvXmlData.DataSource = dt;
            gvXmlData.DataBind();
            btnExportData.Visible = true;
```

Comment: can you show sample value in excel file?

Comment: 3/31/2014 9:00:00 AM this data shows in a single column rather than in a separate column

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing same cell value in both **StartDate** and **StartTime**.
Most probably next cell should give you time value.

Also you can format date time same as specified in XML e.g. (mm/dd/YYYY)
Same goes with time hours minutes and seconds.

see code example here:

```
string sDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
string sTime = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();  
DateTime dDateTime;     
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
//cond: for checking the datetime parsing
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(sDate, "M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDateTime))
{   
    //sDate  = dDateTime.ToString("M/dd/yyyy");
    //dr["StartDate"] = sDate;  
            dr["StartDate"] = dDateTime;
}   
//cond: for checking the datetime parsing
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(sTime, "hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDateTime))
{   
    //sTime  = dDateTime.ToString("h:mm:ss");
    //dr["StartTime"] = sTime;
              dr["StartTime"] = dDateTime;  
}
```

Comment: say [0] gives me date & [1] gives me time but this is not i am getting.Either [0] or [1] both gives me date & time in same cell

Comment: Please post your output here. You need to apply format on both date and time to get desired values.

Comment: my output which i got  
**StartDate** **StartTime**
3/24/2014 12:00AM 3/31/2014 09:00AM

Comment: Try out above code example. You need to parse into dateTime data type and extract only date and time as required. Check link for other formats as well http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: What is data type specified for **StartDate** and **StartTime** columns in DataTable?

Comment: dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StartDate", typeof(DateTime)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StartTime", typeof(DateTime)));
& i cannot change the data type for this because it matches my table value parameter

Comment: try assigning parsed dateTime directly to columns. Note above changes in the code.

Comment: sorry no changes have been done.it gives the same result

Comment: How you are exporting data to excel file?

Comment: in **gvXmlData** after **DataBind()** values are shown in required format? Still what is happening inside **btnExportData** is required.

Comment: look i export data in excel because i want to check the format of data. on my btnExportData click the whole data is export to excel & i haven't code any thing special for this because this is just temporary code for excel so there is no problem  in that code. If i change the type of "StartDate" from datetime to string it gives me the result what i want but it create problem in my db.

Comment: gvXmlData.DataSource = dt;
gvXmlData.Columns["StartTime"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss";
gvXmlData.DataBind();

Comment: sorry this is not working & i don't think it is a feasible solution because if i remove my grid & directly want to save data in database,it fails

Answer (score 0):

try with `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
string cellValue = "3/31/2014 9:00:00 AM";// this can be a cell value from excel file like ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString()
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
            cellValue, 
            "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string startDate  = date.ToString("M/dd/yyyy");
string startTime  = date.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: but i am calling XML file. I just post sample XML format of my XML file.Date & Time must be changed..

Comment: date & time is not coming in a single string. It have a separate tag.. see my question